# does adal.js support Authorization Code Grant Flow?

Tags: javascript, azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, adal

For a while now I had a .Net WPF application that uses Adal.Net to perform (what i believe is) an Authorization code grant flow against azure active directory to  access a web API (which is looking for a bearer token in the request).

For this purpose I'm using 2 AAD applications: MyServer (which represents the server) and MyClient (which represents the WPF client). In the azure portal I configued Myclient with permission to access MyServer.

When calling `AcquireToken` from my WPF application i'm supplying `MyClient.ClientId` as the client ID and `MyServer.ResourceUrl` as the resource id, and everything works as expected.

Now I have a website (that only serves static pages using IIS - it does not have asp.net nor node.js as web servers).

I would like to my browser to perform the same flow the .Net native app performed.

I've looked at adal.js but wasn't able to find an easy way to do it.

Must I implement [the entire flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx) by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rony, AAD doesn't support cross origin calls on the token endpoint - so you won't be able to implement the auth code grant OAuth flow in JS (the token request using the code will fail). AAD supports the implicit grant OAuth flow for the scenario you describe (single page app calling a web api).

ADAL.js implements the implicit grant flow. Please let us know if you have any issues using it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks! would the ADAL.js implicit grant flow work if my single-page app is being served from a different URL than the ajax API it needs to call?

Comment: The OAuth flow will indeed work and your SPA will get an access token - however you'll only be able to make AJAX calls to your cross-origin WebAPI if your API supports CORS - you can enable CORS selectively for the SPA origin.

Comment: i've noticed that native flow (using adal .net) the audience in the token is the client ID of the **server** side app, but in the case of adal.js the audience is the client ID of the **client** side app. This means I need to allow another audience on the server side for each new website that uses my server side API. Is there a way to authenticate using adal.js such that the audience will be the server side app (like what i'm doing with native client)?